# jQuery Load Content into DIV and retain parent Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to use this

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    var data = 'testing'
    $("#about").on("click", function() {
        $("#main-content").load("/about.html");
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click the "About" button, it loads the HTML page "about.html" into the div called "main-content". But I have 2 issues

1. When it loads, it loads the "about.html" page into the whole page rather than just inside the "main-content" div
2. When I load the "about.html" I want to be able to access the JavaScript variable "var data" from the main page

Are these both possible?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML. Regarding 2, you need to move the var declaration outside the function, to the top level of your script.

Comment: You mentioned an "About" button, but if that is actually referring to an `<a id="about" href="/about.html">About</a>` then clicking it will also navigate to the href (unless you specifically prevent the default behavior in your jQuery event handler).

Answer (score 0):

Unless about.html is HTML and inline CSS only,
ifrmae is for this purpose.

```
<iframe src="about.html" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue: the about.html page should *actually* be loaded only inside the main-content div. Maybe the css makes the about page fill everything. Maybe there's another javascript in the code causing this issue. The browser inspector should help debugging it.

Second issue: One possible way is to write the variable content into the html then fetching it later. The jQuery data does that creating/reading data attributes on html tags:

```
// javascript in current page
var foo = 'testing';
$("#main-content").data('myvar', foo);

// javascript in about.html
var bar = $("#main-content").data('myvar'); // equals 'testing'
```